# SmartGWT calendar widget, click events do not work

Tags: gwt, calendar, widget, smartgwt

I am using GWT, mor eprecisely SmartGWT for my application. I have a Window layout which sets the basic layout of my page as following :

window (smartGWT window)
 - dockPanel
  - simplePanel in each of the dockPanel parts

now, when adding the smartGWT calendar widget to one of the simplePanels (e.g. East positioned, which represents the "body" in my layout), it is displayed correctly, but the default events for switching the month and adding events do not work. 
Since it works well, if i use the calendar widget on an empty page (without any window-layout), i assume that there are problems with the click-handling of the calendar widget if used within a simplePanel within a window...do i have to pass the click events somehow to the base SmartGWT window ? Can it be a problem that I add the calendar to the simple panel and the simplepanel to dockPanel and the dockpanel to the window ? can this cause any trouble ?

Thanks for any help or hint !

Answer (score 0):

If you're mixing GWT & SmartGWT widgets, then that can be a possible reason. Try to avoid such mix.